# How to check precondition before yield call(..)

Tags: redux-saga

I have a saga for handling uploading of files to my server. A watcher is triggered by one of multiple Redux actions:

- FILE_PROCESS_SUCCESS: a successful processing of a file (i.e. resizing an image)
- NETWORK_INTERNET_ON: getting an Internet connection after an outage.

The watcher uses the saga helper **effects.throttle**, for now.

If a file gets ready for upload (FILE_PROCESS_SUCCESS) the save-function gets called even if there is no Internet connection. The first thing I do in the save-function is to check for Internet so I don't make the API call in vain.

It would be nicer to NOT call the save-function at all if there is no Internet. How could I accomplish that with ReduxSaga?

**What I want is:** A throttled call that is triggered by one of multiple Redux actions, but only if *isConnected = true*.

#### The save-function

```
function* saveUnsavedFilesToServer(action) {
  //Don't even bother to try saving if we don't have an Internet connection
  let isConnected = yield call(NetInfo.isConnected.fetch);
  if (!isConnected) return;

  //..send files to server
}
```

#### The watcher

```
function* watchToSaveFilesToServer() {
  yield throttle(
    1000,
    [FILE_PROCESS_SUCCESS, NETWORK_INTERNET_ON],
    saveUnsavedFilesToServer
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. But I'd welcome comments on the solution. Is this a good solution?

#### My special version of the throttle generator:

```
export function* throttleIfConnected(ms, pattern, task, ...args) {
  const throttleChannel = yield actionChannel(pattern, buffers.sliding(1));

  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(throttleChannel);
    const isConnected = yield call(NetInfo.isConnected.fetch);
    if (isConnected) yield fork(task, ...args, action);
    yield call(delay, ms);  
  }
}
```

#### The original throttle function as described in the Saga docs

https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/index.html#throttlems-pattern-saga-args

```
function* throttle(ms, pattern, task, ...args) {
  const throttleChannel = yield actionChannel(pattern, buffers.sliding(1))

  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(throttleChannel)
    yield fork(task, ...args, action)
    yield call(delay, ms)
  }
}
```

#### Edit >

This seems to work really well. I went on and made a **callIfConnected** as well.

```
export function* callIfConnected(task, ...args) {
  let isConnected = yield call(NetInfo.isConnected.fetch);
  if (isConnected) yield call(task, ...args);
}
```

I use the *IfConnected* helpers whenever a generator with API calls are involved. No need to try the API calls if there is no Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I got an alernative, not for throttle but for NetInfo check,

```
const x = yield call(NetInfo.getConnectionInfo);
    if(x.type !== "none"){
            yield all([call(bestSellers), call(products)]);
        }
    }
```